# How to prevent Git from skipping the pre-commit hook when using git commit -a?

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit

We've got this repo for all our Puppet configs. I wrote the following to validate any changed .pp files and bail out of the commit if validation fails. The pre-commit script runs properly when triggered by `git commit` but `git commit -a` seems to skip the hook altogether. We use `git commit -a` exclusively so this behaviour is a bit of a deal breaker.

Am I doing something wrong? Alternatively, what could I do to duplicate git commit -a's behaviour in the pre-commit script?

```
#!/bin/bash
# check puppet files for errors before pushing to repo
for name in `git diff --name-only`; do
    if [[ $name == *.pp ]]; then
        path="$(pwd)/$name"
        puppet parser validate "$path"
        r=$?
        if [ $r -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: I assume this script is running in `.git/hooks/pre-comit`?

Comment: Yeah, .git/hooks/pre-commit

Comment: Try adding `--cached` to your `git diff` command. This will cause `git diff` to diff against *staged changes* instead of unstaged ones, which I believe is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre-commit hooks run on every commit, even when the -a option is specified. Confirm it by creating this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running"
```

Put the script into `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, editing and staging a file, and then:

```
$ git commit -am "Commit"
Running
[master f042adf] Commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

`git diff` by default diffs against unstaged changes. For example, edit README.md then:

```
$ git diff --name-only
README.md
$ git add -A
$ git diff --name-only
$
```

Once the changes had been staged, they no longer appeared in `git diff`.

The -a option on `git commit` stages the changes before executing the pre-commit hook. For example, if we change our pre-commit hook to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running"
git diff --name-only
```

Edit `README.md` again, then:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ .git/hooks/pre-commit
Running
README.md
$ git commit -m "Commit"
Running
README.md
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   README.md

no changes added to commit
```

The changes showed up in the diff output, but were not committed. But:

```
$ git commit -am "Commit"
Running
[master a357465] Commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

This time, using the -a option, the changes did not show in the diff output (because they were on the stage) but they were committed.

So add the `--cached` option to the `git diff` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running"
git diff --name-only --cached
```

Then, after making another change to`README.md`:

```
$ git commit -am "Commit"
Running
README.md
[master eaab554] Commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

The answer is the `--cached` option on `git diff`.

Comment: Credit should go to @chris who figured it out in the comment.